# How do I code 360 degree movement with the thumbstick in XNA Visual Studio

Tags: xna, rotation, controls

Okay, so I'm preparing to make a game and it all centers around a circle that the player controls. This game is a top down view. The gun is pointing north or "up". I've created a spritesheet where the the gun points to 4 directions inbetween each right angle. So between the gun pointing ^ and it pointing > there are 4 other positions. This is true all the way round.

What I want to do is code the game so that if you were to twirl the Right Thumbstick around in a circle it would animate the gun going around the full 360. But I don't know how to do this as I've only worked with basic directions so far. And even if I got the thumbstick axis operating I'm not sure how I would reference each point as a location of the thumbstick.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Gets us the rotation from the stick: (taking this from memory, som might be reverse order etc)
float radians = Math.Atan2(GamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y, GamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X);

//Top half: 0 = stick to the right to Pi = stick to the left.
//Bottom half: 0 = stick to the right to -Pi = stick to the left.

//I'll just do this for 4 directions, as I have limited time, and the concept should be obvious:

if ((radians > Math.Pi * -0.25f) && (radians < Math.Pi * 0.25f))
    //Direction is Right
else if ((radians >= Math.Pi * 0.25f) && (radians < Math.Pi * 0.75f))
    //Direction is Up
else if ((radians >= Math.Pi * 0.75f) || (radians <= Math.Pi * -0.75f))
    //Direction is Left
else if ((radians <= Math.Pi * -0.25f) && (radians > Math.Pi * -0.75f))
    //Direction is Down
```

To get more angles, you just do more of this. you may find it easier to just use the Thumbstick:

```
Vector2 stick = GamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left;
stick.Normalize();

if (stick.X >= 0.5f) (NE, E, SE)
{
    if (stick.Y >= 0.5f)
        //Direction is NE
    else if (stick.Y <= -0.5f)
        //Direction is SE
    else
        //Direction is E
}
else if (stick.X <= -0.5f) (NW, W, SW)
{
    if (stick.Y >= 0.5f)
        //Direction is NW
    else if (stick.Y <= -0.5f)
        //Direction is SW
    else
        //Direction is W
}
else if (stick.Y >= 0.5f)
    //Direction is N
else if (stick.Y <= -0.5f)
    //Direction is S
else
    //Direction is nothing. should not happen
```

Edit; To shoot bullets in the direction of the thumbstick, just use the thumbstick normalized * speed as velocity for the bullets.